# How To Convert (2018-09-05T09:00:06.540486Z) Into (2018-09-05) In python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have searched for a solution but I have not found any, I have a dictionary like This

```
tmp ={
    'admission_date':adm.admission_date,
    'course':adm.course.name
}
```

In models.py i have admission_date to `DatetimeField`. In the Get Function  I want to format this date like this 2018-09-05 By removing all part 
How can i do This.

Comment: `adm.admission_date.date()` ?

Comment: Call `.date()` in it, so `adm.admission_date.date()`.

Comment: Thanks A lot It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If you want **`datetime`** object, use [**`.date()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date)

```
tmp = {
    'admission_date': adm.admission_date.date(),
    'course': adm.course.name
}
```

else if you want *string representation*, use  [**`.strftime()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

```
tmp = {
    'admission_date': adm.admission_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'course': adm.course.name
}
```